# requestAnimFrame Stack Overflow PIXI js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, requestanimationframe, pixi.js

I am actually trying to develop a small browser game using the Pixi.js engine.

I want it to have a real architecture so I am using a brunch server (with coffee-script).

I want to reproduce the example 1 (http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/1/).

I am using an object called Game. The App.init() calls Game.init().

Game.coffee :

```
Game =
w: null
h: null
man: null
stage: null
renderer: null

init: ->
    @w = 300
    @h = 400

    @stage = new PIXI.Stage( 0x66FF99 )
    @renderer = new PIXI.WebGLRenderer(@w, @h)

    document.body.appendChild( @renderer.view )     

    @man = new PIXI.Sprite( PIXI.Texture.fromImage('../images/bob.png') )

    @man.anchor.x = 0.5
    @man.anchor.y = 0.5

    @man.position.x = @w/2
    @man.position.y = @h/2


    @stage.addChild( @man )
    console.debug 'Man created'

    @update()

    return 

update: ->
    requestAnimFrame( @update() )

    @man.rotation += 0.1

    if @stage.renderable then console.debug 'we can render !'
    else 'we can not render !'

    @renderer.render( @stage )

    return

module.exports = Game
```

But when I am trying to run this I get this on my console :

```
Man created ! 
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size
```

It says it comes from the line where I define the update function. I know it has something to see with the requestAnimFrame line but i don't know why.

I am pretty new to animation and coffee-script and even Object.

So if you could help me fix my problem this would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `update` function, you're calling `@update()`, which is causing stackoverflow. The function [`requestAnimFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) expects a callback function as parameter:

```
requestAnimFrame @update
```

*You should use same line inside `init` function.*

---

*Not related to question, but this might help you:*

Few tips on your coffeescript code:

- You don't need a return every time, last line automatically turns into return. If you're not using returned value, there's no point in explicitly returning.
- The code: `if @stage.renderable then console.debug 'we can render !'
  else 'we can not render !'` probably doesn't works as you'd expect, because `console.debug` is called only when `@stage.renderable` evaluates to true, if not, you'll only put `'we can not render !'` string inside the code, which doesn't do anything. What you probably wanted to achieve is `console.debug if @stage.renderable then 'we can render !' else 'we can not render !'`
- Although this notation is correct, coffeescript has [classes](http://coffeescript.org/#classes), I recommend you to use that, instead of creating objects.
- If you're not sure what coffee code does, use `try coffeescript` tab on [coffeescript official page](http://coffeescript.org/). Or use `coffee -c` and check it out locally. If you're using editor, such as [sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/), [atom](https://atom.io/) or any of IDEs, such as [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), they all have options to directly preview coffeescript code as javascript.

Comment: Huh, this is still not working. I still have this error. It says it comes from this line : `update: ->` In the console I have got a tons of this : `module.exports.Game.update` As a more precise log error. As the function was exported too much times.

Comment: Ooh, I've figured it out now, it's such a small detail. You're using `update()`, but `requestAnimFrame` accepts function, **NOT** function call. I've also edited this in my answer.

Comment: Alright, I figured out to make it works. I used : `requestAnimFrame @update` But I told me that `@update` was not a function. So I looked upon and find that `requestAnimFrame @update.bind(@)` was working. Indeed, `function.bind(this)` is used to return a function usable in any case with **this = this from update**

Comment: The way you did it in your question should work. If you're using a class, you're correct, that way this is bound to most inner function. If you've read coffee docs, you probably saw `->` and `=>` (so called fat arrow) being used. What "fat arrow" does is bind `@` to class instead of default javascript behaviour, which is `this` from innermost function.